# Doubts About Core Data NSManagedObject Deep Copy

Tags: core-data, object, data-integrity, cloning

I have a situation where I must copy one NSManagedObject from the main context into an editing context. It sounds unnecessary to most people as I have seen in similar situations described in Stackoverflow but I looks like I need it.

In my app there are many views in a tab bar and every view handles different information that is related to the other views. I think I need multiple MOCs since the user may jump from tab to tab and leave unsaved changes in some tab but maybe it saves data in some other tab/view so if that happens the changes in the rest of the views are saved without user consent and in the worst case scenario makes the app crash.

For adding new information I got away by using an adding MOC and then merging changes in both MOCs but for editing is not that easy. I saw a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730832/how-can-i-duplicate-or-copy-a-core-data-managed-object/2936660#2936660) in Stackoverflow but the app crashes since my data model doesn't seem to use NSMutableSet for the relationships (I don't think I have a many-to-many relationship, just one-to-many) I think it can be modified so I can retrieve the relationships as if they were attributes

```
for (NSString *attr in relationships) {
    [cloned setValue:[source valueForKey:attr] forKey:attr];
}
```

but I don't know how to merge the changes of the cloned and original objects. I think I could just delete the object from the main context, then merge both contexts and save changes in the main context but I don't know if is the right way to do it. I'm also concerned about database integrity since I'm not sure that the inverse relationships will keep the same reference to the cloned object as if it were the original one.

Can some one please enlighten me about this?

Comment: Well, it appears that the piece of code above didn't work at all, now that I see it is pretty obvious. All the documentation that I have found so far talks about retrieving NSMutableSet but my data model classes only contains NSSet's for the relationships.

Comment: Ok it seems that my sight failed me. My one-to-many relation didn't was an NSSet it was a Core Data entity. So of course it was my mistake.

Comment: But right now what I used was a custom object that holds the same data types as the Data Model entity and for the relationships I use an NSString that holds the related object name and is validated later. Then when the user actually saves I edit the object right in the mainContext set the the relationship by fetching the related object based on the NSString name and save it immediately. I don't know if that is a professional way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, lots of questions and randomness in this one.  First, you do not need to add comments to your own question, better to edit the question itself.

Second, you don't need multiple `NSManagedObjectContext` instances if you are running a single threaded application.  Your entire application can easily run off of a single instance.  Multiple contexts are for rare edge cases and multi-threading situations.

By using a single context it will resolve all of your issues with your attempts to clone.  However, if you are still wondering how to do a deep copy of a `NSManagedObject` you can get some guidance from the example code in my book at [The Pragmatic Programmers](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data); the source code of which is free to download.

### Update

All `NSManagedObjectContext` instances are "editing ones".  You only need a single context per thread.  You can easily ask the context for the non-inserted entities if you want to delete them before a save and you can easily save entities as they are changed.  Except for some ***extreme*** edge cases you do not need a second context.

### Update

You are still creating more work for yourself then you need to.  You don't need to save an object for the view to go away. You can leave as many objects as you want in an unsaved state in the context.

You are going to spend more time debugging dealing a deep copy of objects than it is worth with the design you are describing.  If you are going to use more than one context, make sure they are attached to the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` so that you don't need to copy the objects around, you can just save the "secondary" context and then catch the save notification in the main context.

Comment: Hello again Marcus. I apologize for my carelessness. I fell a little intimidated now knowing that you are the author of the book. 

I also feel ashamed since it appears you are the only one that is taking the time to post in my threads.

I'm not sure if I am working in a poorly designed app but although it is not a threaded app I still feel the need of using at least two MOC's the main one and an editing one.

In the mean time I'm going to check the code of your book, thanks a lot for that by the way.

Comment: I managed to clean up my code and in two classes I removed almost half of the code. U r right I could use just 1 MOC but I'm sure u already know that ;) but I prefer using 2 at least for creating new objects since in my app the user can jump between views, create related objects and leave unsaved changes. I could get away by forcing the user to save or dismiss before jumping to other view but we don't want that. For editing NSUndoManager will be more useful although I wish there was a more elegant way to restore an object to it's saved state without rolling back the whole MOC.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarifications and all your help Mr. Marcus. This is what I did. Basically I created a new MOC that shares everything with the main MOC and then I call ObjectWithID: and send the ID of the original NSMO, the when the user saves, the App saves the MOC and merge the content of the second MOC with the main MOC. I didn't have to do any NSMO deep copy.

Comment: Marcus, first of all, thanks for sharing this! Just to confirm, I'm looking in PPImportOperation.m in the MultiThreading project. That's the deep copy sample, correct? (At first I thought associateObject:parent: was not creating new objects, but in fact it does ultimately call recursively back into copyPropertiesFromObject:toObject:parent:, so I suspect this is it.) Since I don't believe I have an extreme edge case, I don't think I need a second MOC, so I should be able to get away with just using the current MOC. (This example appears to use a second one, which makes sense for the example.)

Comment: If you are using a single MOC then you don't need to copy the object at all.  However, if you are using two contexts then yes that example shows the concepts.