# Copy array of NSManagedObject objects in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, copy, swift4

I have an array of `NSManagedObject's` and I want to copy them to a new array in order to manipulate them and not save the changes after the user is done.

**The array:**

```
var origQuestions: [Questions]?
```

**This is how I retreive the data from CoreData:**

```
self.origQuestions = MainDb.sharedInstance.randomQuestions(entity: "Questions", count: self.questionToShow)
```

**This is what I need in Objective-C, but I want to know how to do so in Swift 4:**

```
NSMutableArray *questionsCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.origQuestions copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: COuld you narrow down your question by showing some code of what you've tried so far ?

Comment: @Christophe I've edited my question. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: Ok.  Do the swift answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2730832/3723423) help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate that Objective-C code into Swift you do:

```
var questionsCopy = NSArray(array: origQuestions, copyItems:true) as! [Questions]
```

But since you declared `origQuestions` as optional, it needs to be:

```
var questionsCopy = origQuestions != nil ? NSArray(array: origQuestions!, copyItems:true) as? [Questions] : nil
```

Whether that fully works (Objective-C or Swift) with `NSManagedObject` or not is another question. See [How can I duplicate, or copy a Core Data Managed Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730832/how-can-i-duplicate-or-copy-a-core-data-managed-object) and its Swift answers for code that specifically covers doing deep copies of `NSManagedObject` instances.

Comment: I actually used the link to the question you gave in your answer, found there an approach with Swift 4. Great answer! Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544796/1138498

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you originally want that Objective-C line? And did you try it in Swift after translating it as shown in my answer and what was the result?

Comment: I didn't want that Obj-C line. I was just trying to show how I used to do it in Obj-C and didn't know how to do so in Swift. Because in Swift you need to clone the array differently I guess.